# Spring Security + AAD: invalid_token_response

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth, azure-active-directory

After signing in to the Azure Active Directory I get a 401 back from the POST to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token`.

I registered my application in my AD and gave it the permissions `user.read` and .... I changed the manifest and set `oauth2AllowImplicitFlow` to `true`.

Tenant id, client id and client secret are correctly filled in. I tried to change them to double check and changed it to the correct ones.

The web security config is the following, this is from the [Microsoft/azure-spring-boot](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-spring-boot/blob/master/azure-spring-boot-samples/azure-active-directory-spring-boot-backend-sample/src/main/java/sample/aad/security/AADOAuth2LoginSecurityConfig.java) repository.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
class AADOAuth2LoginSecurityConfig(private val oidcUserService: OAuth2UserService<OidcUserRequest, OidcUser>) : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()

                .userInfoEndpoint()
                .oidcUserService(oidcUserService)
    }
}
```

If I clone the sample and fill in the required configuration in `application.properties` everything works fine. If I start a brand new project, add the security, web, azure active directory, spring-security-oauth2-client and spring-security-oauth2-jose I get the 401.

The versions in use are the following

**Spring Boot**
2.1.0.RELEASE

**[Azure Spring Boot Version](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-spring-boot)**
2.0.7

**application.properties**

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.client-id=xxxxxx
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.client-secret=xxxxxx
azure.activedirectory.tenant-id=xxxxxx
azure.activedirectory.active-directory-groups=Users
```

After spitting through the debug logs the only difference I can see between the sample and the fresh project is that the HTTP Basic auth is different. The old version URL encodes the password (it contains non-url-safe characters) and then base64 encodes it as a whole `base64(clientId:urlEncode(clientSecret))`. The new version does **not** do this, can this be the actual problem? If so, how can I solve it since it's a change in the library then.

Comment: For now the sample you referenced is depends on spring boot 2.0.x, Can you have a try from your fresh project ? And you may add the details of the difference between URL.

Comment: This solved my problem for now. The auto configuration didn't seem to work (or works differently) in 2.1.0+...