# Spring Security + AAD: invalid_token_response follow-up with latest available spring-boot version (2.1.2)

Tags: spring-boot, azure-active-directory, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I am facing the same issue as posted in the question [Spring Security + AAD: invalid_token_response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53539756/spring-security-aad-invalid-token-response)

I did try 2.1.0, it didn't help. 
I am currently using Spring-boot 2.1.2, spring-security-oauth2-client 5.1.3 and i am still getting the same error

I am sharing my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>perdict</groupId>
    <artifactId>ouath2-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>ouath2-client</name>

  <build>
    <finalName>predictouath2client</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <azure.version>2.1.2</azure.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-active-directory-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>       

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security.oauth.boot/spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${azure.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

and the WebSecurityConfig looks like:-

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private OAuth2UserService<OidcUserRequest, OidcUser> oidcUserService; 

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .oauth2Login()
        .userInfoEndpoint()
        .oidcUserService(oidcUserService);
}
```

the application.yaml looks like:-

```
spring:
 security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          azure:
            client-id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            client-secret: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            client-authentication-method: basic
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri-template: '{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}'
            scope: openid, https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read
            client-name: Microsoft Azure
            client-alias: azure
        provider:
          azure:
            authorization-uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/authorize
            token-uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/token
            user-info-uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/openid/userinfo            
            jwk-set-uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/discovery/keys
            user-name-attribute: name

azure:
  activedirectory:
    tenant-id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    active-directory-groups: Users
```

The detail error from the log files is

```
    2019-02-08 05:48:28.612 DEBUG 99981 --- [nio-8010-exec-4] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Response 401 UNAUTHORIZED
2019-02-08 05:48:28.619 DEBUG 99981 --- [nio-8010-exec-4] .s.a.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher : No event was found for the exception org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException
2019-02-08 05:48:28.620 DEBUG 99981 --- [nio-8010-exec-4] .s.o.c.w.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter : Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException: [invalid_token_response] An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the OAuth 2.0 Access Token Response: 401 Unauthorized

org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException: [invalid_token_response] An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the OAuth 2.0 Access Token Response: 401 Unauthorized
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.authentication.OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.java:143) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:175) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.java:186) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
```

Comment: I found a open-issue in ms azure documentation related to this https://github.com/Azure/azure-docs-sdk-java/issues/731